# How to remove ONLY alphanumeric characters with number notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i need help for remove non alpanumeric characters on notepad++ with number into non alpanumeric characters, please see example:

```
ZTE Blade L3 (4)

ZTE Blade Spark (23)

ZTE Blade V7 (5)

ZTE Blade V7 Lite (6)

ZTE Blade V8 (14)

ZTE Blade V9 (3)
```

and after remove :

```
ZTE Blade L3

ZTE Blade Spark

ZTE Blade V7

ZTE Blade V7 Lite

ZTE Blade V8

ZTE Blade V9
```

Comment: From your sample data, it appears that you just want to remove the numbers in parentheses.  Is that the only use case, or are there other examples of removing things?

Comment: yes remove the numbers in parentheses and parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers in parentheses would always occur at the end of each line, you may use the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \s+\(\d+\)$
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo